# How can I subtract one row to the row above?

Tags: r

Let's say I have a the following dataframe df:

```r
df <- data.frame("a"=c(2,5,9,3), "b"=(1:4))

 a | b
-------
 2 | 1
 5 | 2
 9 | 3
 3 | 4
```

I now want to create a new column, "c", which values are the difference between the said column (n) and the column above (n-1) so in this example it would be row differences for column a and not b.

The final output I am looking for is the following:

```r
 a | b | c
-----------
 2 | 1 | NA
 5 | 2 | 3
 9 | 3 | 4
 3 | 4 | -6
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are looking for `diff()`

Comment: You're subtracting columns not rows, no? I just don't get it, what of b?

Comment: @NelsonGon I think the OP wants `diff(a)`

Answer (score 3):

Using `dplyr`:

```
df <- data.frame("a"=c(2,5,9,3), "b"=(1:4))

library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(c = a - lag(a))
```